# How do you remove placeholder?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I don't want a placeholder at all. Unfortunately, neither

```
placeholder=""
```

or

```
placeholder=" "
```

works. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: can you add more details. i.e whole element

Answer (score -1):

```
$scope.placeholder = "";

<input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as `<input type="text" placeholder="">`.